# MyPy does not recognise x[idx] as boolean after isinstance(x[idx], bool)

Tags: python, type-inference, mypy, isinstance

**Core issue**
MyPy is not able to identify / validate the return value `x[idx]` as being of boolean type.

```python
if isinstance(x[idx], bool) is True:
        return x[idx]
```

---

**Complete example code**

```python
from typing import Union, Optional

x: dict[str, Union[bool, str]] = {'a': True, 'b': 'foo'}


def return_if_bool(idx: str) -> Optional[bool]:
    if isinstance(x[idx], bool):
        return x[idx]
    return None


print(return_if_bool('a'))
```

---

**MyPy returns**
`8: error: Incompatible return value type (got "bool | str", expected "bool | None")  [return-value]`

---

**Workaround**
What works is using typing.cast:

```python
return typing.cast(bool, x[idx])
```

A “cleaner”<sup>(imo)</sup> workaround avoiding cast was pointed out by @Wombatz – assign `y = x[idx]` as in:

```python
    y: Union[bool, str] = x[idx]
    if isinstance(y, bool):
        return y
```

---

**Why?**
I would expect this to work without having to resort to `typing.cast()` or assigning to a variable `y = x[idx]`, but couldn’t fully figure out why it doesn’t, especially as it looks incredibly trivial.

---

**Possible explanations**
@Wombatz input that MyPy cannot know that x[idx] will return the same value on repeated access makes sense and gets very close to fully answering this question. However, MyPy seems to be quite capable of recognising behaviour as exhibited by e.g. iterators, so its still somewhat odd.

Comment: Get rid of the `is True` - that is completely pointless (the result is the same boolean value that `isinstance()` returned), and may be preventing mypy from interpreting that line as a type assertion.

Comment: @jasonharper: removing is True does not resolve the issue  (tested + removed from the example code / updated the post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the dictionary twice, but you only check the result once. Mypy cannot know that repeated access to the same key will always return the same type (and it should not, because a dict sub class could do something weird).

So in short: only access the dict once, check that type and return the value.

```
value = x[idx]
if isinstance(value, bool):
    return value
return None
```

The narrowing of the name `value` is persistent, but the narrowing of an arbitrary expression is not.

This also holds for attribute access or other function calls.

So, if you want to type check something for mypy and it "forgets" the check, always try to save the expression in a variable.

*I believe this is a duplicate, but it's impossible to find on a mobile device*

Appendix: here is an object that would violate the typing rules, if mypy didnt "forget" about the instance check

```py
class MyDict(dict[str, bool | str]):
    def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> str | bool:
        if randrange(2) == 1:
            return "hi"
        return True
```

Of course this is a silly implementation, but the more general case - where a sub class could return different variants of a union for identical method calls - is treated in the same way by mypy.

So to answer that part of your question: mypy apparently just does not have a specialization for the type narrowing when accessing dicts, even when it can be proven that the dict is not a subclass.

Comment: @PatrickC this answer mentioned nothing about iterators and has nothing to do with iterators.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: ok, will re-phrase the comments

Comment: @PatrickC it isn't an issue of phrasing, this answer is absolutely correct. `mypy` *cannot know that the expression `x[idx]` won't change values, even if `x` is some dict (and crucially, that means some dict subtype)

Comment: @PatrickC i added a code example of a "dict" that would break static typing, if the code in your question would be allowed

Comment: just read @Wombatz latest response and looked at the example code: Question convincingly answered!